# Split function is not giving expected output

Tags: regex, kotlin, split

I am trying to split a string by using Regex = **\], \[** but unfortunately it is not giving me the expected answer

For the code

```
val splittedList: List<String> = userProgramValue.split("\\], \\[")
```

Where:

```json
userProgramValue = {
    name=opm monday 1, 
    start=04:30, end=06:30
}, 
{
    name=opm monday 2, 
    start=09:00 am, end=11:00 am
}, 
{
    start=12:00 pm, 
    end=02:00 pm, 
    class=opm monday 3
}], 
[{
    name=opm tuesday 1,
    start=11:30am,
    end=01:30pm
}, 
{
    start=10:00 am,
    end=12:00 pm,
    class=opm tuesday 2
}, 
{
    start=02:00 pm,
    end=04:00 pm,
    class=opm tuesday 3
}
```

When I debug the code instead of giving splitted string with length of 2 it is giving only one string with length equal 1.

**Expected output**
Splitted string with 2 values:

```json
{
    name=opm monday 1,
    start=04:30, end=06:30
},
{
    name=opm monday 2,
    start=09:00 am,
    end=11:00 am
},
{
    start=12:00 pm,
    end=02:00 pm,
    class=opm monday 3
}

{
    name=opm tuesday 1,
    start=11:30am,
    end=01:30pm
},
{
    start=10:00 am,
    end=12:00 pm,
    class=opm tuesday 2
},
{
    start=02:00 pm,
    end=04:00 pm,
    class=opm tuesday 3
}
```

**Output Obtained:**

```json
[{
    name=opm monday 1,
    start=04:30,
    end=06:30
}, 
{
    name=opm monday 2,
    start=09:00 am,
    end=11:00 am
},
{
    start=12:00 pm,
    end=02:00 pm,
    class=opm monday 3
}],
[{
    name=opm tuesday 1,
    start=11:30am,
    end=01:30pm
},
{
    start=10:00 am,
    end=12:00 pm,
    class=opm tuesday 2
},
{
    start=02:00 pm,
    end=04:00 pm,
    class=opm tuesday 3
}]
```

Debug session of Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: What is the exact output you want here?

Comment: I want exact output to be splitted string with 2 values:

{name=opm monday 1, start=04:30, end=06:30}, {name=opm monday 2, start=09:00 am, end=11:00 am}, {start=12:00 pm, end=02:00 pm, class=opm monday 3}

{name=opm tuesday 1, start=11:30am, end=01:30pm}, {start=10:00 am, end=12:00 pm, class=opm tuesday 2}, {start=02:00 pm, end=04:00 pm, class=opm tuesday 3}

Comment: This function does not split by regex, but by exact string.

Answer (score 0):

You need not escape the square brackets.
Simply use,

```kotlin
val splittedList: List<String> = userProgramValue.split("], [")
```

Comment: And this is because Kotlin's [`split()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) function has several overloads, allowing the delimiters to be given either as a `Regex`/`Pattern`, or (like this question) as `String`(s)/`Char`(s). The latter are interpreted as _literal_ strings, not regexes. (This differs from Java, and is a lot less ambiguous.)